# Can you add native lazy loading attribute to an image with media queries?

Tags: css

I have images that display above the fold on a desktop screen, but display below the fold on smaller mobile screens. I would like these images to use the native lazy loading attribute when displaying below the fold. Is there a way to do this with media queries? Thanks

What I'd like to do is:

```
CSS:
              @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                .lazy {
                  loading: lazy;
                }
              }

HTML:
              <img class="lazy" src="photo.jpg">
```

However, it appears as though a CSS method such as this does not exist, so I'm looking for an alternative that will accomplish the same thing.

To clarify, the same image loads above the fold on larger screens and below the fold on smaller screens, and I only want to apply the lazy loading when the image appears below the fold.

Comment: https://blog.webjeda.com/lazy-load-css/

Comment: The article you linked to is about lazy loading CSS files and does not address my question, but thanks for the info.

Comment: Oh sorry. I misread. No css can not add an attribute or attribute value to an html element. Css can style those elements based on the attributes though. But thats backwards to what you want.

Also your lazy loading script should be detecting if the image is visible in the viewport onload. Your question is a bit confusing. But if i answer literally than the answer is no.

Comment: OK, I get it. Do you know of an alternative way to only lazy load an image if it's below the fold?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance - 

This article goes over all the potential ways you can lazy load below the fold. Unless you share your code and what you tried its hard to help u.

Comment: Does it matter? If it's over the fold, it won't lazy load anyway.

Comment: "display above the fold"   what is meant by '"fold" here? i.e. do you mean 600px or some other measure of height not width?

Answer (score 0):

You could just mark all your images as loading="lazy" and give them appropriate heights and widths, including the ones you expect to be above the fold and the browser should handle the loading without you having to think too much about it. Is there a particular reason you don't want to do this?

It's important to note that for lazy loading to work correctly it is best to provide height and width for all your images. See here for why:

https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/#distance-from-viewport-thresholds

Here's a quick example on stackblitz with heights and widths

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-ps8sfq?file=index.html

and one without

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-drlfv9?file=index.html

If you open the network tab in dev tools and filter by img you should see on the former that the images are loaded lazily but on the latter they all get loaded even though they are marked as lazy.

Here is one more without lazy loading. If you have the network tab open with no filter you can compare where the images start loading. For me they start showing up at the same place but with lazy loading and heights/widths it only loads the first 2 as opposed to all of them.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-wjt9jn?file=index.html

Comment: Sorry, for brevity I left out the width and height attributes on my image example, but I always use them in my code. If I read your comments correctly, you are saying that I can use the lazy load attribute on an image, but if the image is above the fold, then the browser will load the image normally, ignoring the loading=lazy. Is that correct?

Comment: Ah yeah of course I see now that that was just an example of what you would like to see. I will add one more example to my answer that will have the same but without lazy loading. If you open the network tab without any filter you can see where the images start loading. For me they start showing up at the same place but with lazy loading it only loads the first 2 as opposed to all of them.